# Python: Plotting three images in one to show before and after

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make an image like the one below which would be made from 3 equally sized arrays that get shown only partially. Is there some way to slice or overplot the three arrays to get a division like this one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Patches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import os

patch1 = ((0,0.3),(0,1),(0.5,1),(0.5,0.5))
patch2 = ((0.5,0.5),(0.5,1),(1,1),(1,0.3))
patch3 = ((0,0),(0,0.3),(0.5,0.5),(1,0.3),(1,0))

# Pictures from Win10 in WSL2
path = r"/mnt/c/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Theme1"

img1 = plt.imread(os.path.join(path, "img1.jpg"))
img2 = plt.imread(os.path.join(path, "img2.jpg"))
img3 = plt.imread(os.path.join(path, "img3.jpg"))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

poly1 = patches.Polygon(patch1, transform=ax.transAxes)
poly2 = patches.Polygon(patch2, transform=ax.transAxes)
poly3 = patches.Polygon(patch3, transform=ax.transAxes)

ip1 = ax.imshow(img1)
ip2 = ax.imshow(img2)
ip3 = ax.imshow(img3)

ip1.set_clip_path(poly1)
ip2.set_clip_path(poly2)
ip3.set_clip_path(poly3)

l1 = lines.Line2D((0, 0.5), (0.3, 0.5), color="w", transform=ax.transAxes)
l2 = lines.Line2D((0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1), color="w", transform=ax.transAxes)
l3 = lines.Line2D((0.5, 1), (0.5, 0.3), color="w", transform=ax.transAxes)

l1.set_linewidth(5)
l2.set_linewidth(5)
l3.set_linewidth(5)

fig.add_artist(l1)
fig.add_artist(l2)
fig.add_artist(l3)


ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That does the job! Do you know if there is a way to get a white line in between them also?

Comment: @Coolcrab First think I would try is setting the line properties of the patches when they are created

Comment: @PaulH Adding `edgecolor='red', linewidth=3` to the patches does not do anything for some reason.

Comment: Updated answer to add lines, you could also just change the poly coordinates to add a gap

Comment: @PaulH because we are not plotting the patches we are using them to mask the images.

Comment: @JasonM It complains about the add artist lines now `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_artist'` I am not sure why. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Hmm what version of Python + MatPlotlib are you using?

Comment: @JasonM Python 3.5.3 and MPL 2.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239289/discussion-between-jason-m-and-coolcrab).

Comment: @JasonM Updating MPL worked! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see there's a good answer here. but I came up with a code, and don't want to discard it.

I think a good way to get this is creating a list of mask using an auxiliar matrix with the angle of every pixel, then dividing the whole angle by the number of imgs and compose with those masks:

1. Imports and loading images (this is to show some result, there's no need to do some large block to load imgs) **the imports are needed**

   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import cv2

   img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.imread("/home/ulises/stackof/composing/coffee.jpg")[:,:,::-1])

   img2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),2)
   img3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(23,23),7)
   imgList = [img,img2,img3]
   plt.imshow(np.hstack(imgList))

with the result [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdmKq.jpg)

Then a function that create the img with angles

```
def rad_img(W,H):
    """create a matrix with size WxH that contains in every
     value the angle in radians to the center of the matrix W/2 ,H/2"""
    return np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: np.pi-np.arctan2(y-W/2,x-H/2) ,(H,W))
```

wich results on something like [[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOS7Y.png)

Last a function that uses this and generate masks with the imgList and ploting the results:

```
def compose_images(imgList):
    "asuming the imgs have the same shape, if not resize then to an unique.."
    nImgs = len(imgList)
    angle = 2*np.pi/nImgs
    h,w = imgList[0].shape[:2]
    radImg = rad_img(w,h)
    outputImg = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(nImgs):
        thisMask = (i*angle<=radImg) * (radImg<(i+1)*angle)
        outputImg += imgList[i]*thisMask[:,:,None]
    
    return outputImg


newImg = compose_images(imgList)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(newImg)
```

this creates an image like this one:

[image]